# где посмотреть квоту в exchange 2007

Tags: администрирование

где посмотреть квоту в microsoft exchange 2007 которая выдаётся для каждого юзера?

Comment: Квоту чего имеено? Если вопрос перевести (перефразировать) на русский - получится "где посмотреть ограничение в exchange 2007"

Comment: квота почты которая выделяется для каждой учётной записи, жаль скрин не могу скинуть